# How do I calculate the size of an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I currently have an app that prints out a big text inside a `TextView` but I'm unsure how I can calculate what the height on the `textView` needs to be so it fits perfectly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is how my text would look like

> This is a cover of Cimorelli's song Million Bucks with my own spin on
>   it :-) Hope you like!!! Download free:
>   http://davedays.com.hostbaby.com/files/Million_Bucks.mp3 (right click
>   and save as)
>
> Ending song "Boy You'll Forget"
>   https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/boy-youll-forget/id605629968
>
> Cimorelli: http://www.youtube.com/cimorellitheband Thanks to Jon for
>   filming! http://www.youtube.com/simplyspoons
>
> Latest episode of Writing Room: http://www.youtube.com/badplanetmusic
>
> HIT ME UP! Twitter: http://www.twitter.com/davedays Facebook:
>   http://www.facebook.com/ddays Merch:
>   http://www.westaspenmerch.com/davedays http://www.davedays.com

Comment: I've resorted to putting the string into a dummy UILabel and telling the label to resize itself to fit.  There are other functions that sound like they'd work, but they don't.

Comment: Related: [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/50467/457406) and [sizeWithFont doesn't give correct height for UITextView if there is a long string in the text being wrapped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2330939/457406)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962641/get-the-nsstring-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "measure" text height you could use something like this:

```
-(CGFloat)measureText:(NSString*)text {  
    CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, CGFLOAT_MAX)];  
    return requiredSize.height;  
}
```

The "220" is the maximum width of the text view - change it for your case - and of course you could change the font type/size.

Also, have a look at [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.